# Dotenv undefined after Browserify

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, browserify

When I run my code with the API key in a string format this code works,
but i wanna use the *.env* variables.
I have installed `npm install dotenv`, made a **.env** file in the same directory.
I know that to use the **.env** you need to `require("dotenv").config()` as early as possible in the script.

Since you can't use the **require** in the browser, I have installed `npm install -g browserify` .

When i run `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` and change javaScript source in Index, this code still works.

When I uncomment the `//require("dotenv").config()` and use the `const apiTest = process.env.API_KEY` for the authentication that's where the problem comes.

Error:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data is undefined
    updateScreen http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:765
    promise callback*updateScreen http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:764
    [4]</</</< http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:783
    EventListener.handleEvent*[4]</</< http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:781
    [4]</< http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:786
    [4]< http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:786
    o http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:1
    r http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:1
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:1
bundle.js:765:25
```

Bundle.js:765:25:

```
function updateScreen() {
  //data is a random word, but it represents the return of  getSuggestions()
  getSuggestions().then((data) => {
    const arrayLengde = data.quotes.length;
    if (1 >= arrayLengde) {
      let poem = data.quotes[0].body;
      let poemAuthor = data.quotes[0].author;
      document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = poemAuthor;
      document.getElementById("responseField").innerHTML = poem;
    } else if (1 <= arrayLengde) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLengde);
      poem = data.quotes[randomIndex].body;
      poemAuthor = data.quotes[randomIndex].author;
      document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = poemAuthor;
      document.getElementById("responseField").innerHTML = poem;
    }
  });
}
```

It is defined because it works if i don't use the **.env**.
After inspecting the Get request HEADER i get back this is what i find:

`Status 401`

```
Authorization: Token token=undefined
```

Main.js:

```
//DOTENV with help from Browserify
//require("dotenv").config()


//info om API
const apiTest = process.env.API_KEY
const apiKey = 'NUMBERS_HERE'
const url = "https://favqs.com/api/";
const queryparam1 = "quotes/?filter=";
const queryparam2 = "&type=tag";

//selecting page element
const inputField = document.querySelector("#input");
const form = document.getElementById("form");

//ajax function
async function getSuggestions() {
  const wordQuery = inputField.value;
  const filterQueryParam = `${queryparam1}${wordQuery}${queryparam2}`;
  const endpoint = `${url}${filterQueryParam}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Token token=${apiKey}`,
      },
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      const data = response.json();

      return data;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function updateScreen() {
  //data is a random word, but it represents the return of  getSuggestions()
  getSuggestions().then((data) => {
    const arrayLengde = data.quotes.length;
    if (1 >= arrayLengde) {
      let poem = data.quotes[0].body;
      let poemAuthor = data.quotes[0].author;
      document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = poemAuthor;
      document.getElementById("responseField").innerHTML = poem;
    } else if (1 <= arrayLengde) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLengde);
      poem = data.quotes[randomIndex].body;
      poemAuthor = data.quotes[randomIndex].author;
      document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = poemAuthor;
      document.getElementById("responseField").innerHTML = poem;
    }
  });
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  updateScreen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add .catch((err) => {}) para v

Comment: please explain your answer, like where the code should be added or why it should be added